# Python Pandas extract columns from .csv

Tags: pandas

I have a .csv file, which I can read in Pandas. The .csv file looks like the following.

```
a b c d e
1 4 3 2 5
6 7 8 3 6
...
```

What I need to achieve is, that I can extract a and b as a column vector and 
[c d e] as a matrix. I used Pandas with the following code to read the .csv file:

pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',',header=None)

But this will give me a vector like this: [[a,b,c,d,e],[1,4,3,2,5],...]

How can I extract the columns? I heared about df.iloc, but this cannot be used here, since after pd.read_csv there is only one column.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with:

```
ds = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',',header=0)
column_a = ds["a"]
matrix = ds[["c","d","e"]]
```